# Loopback - Unable to connect to Mongo DB Atlas using mongodb+srv Protocol from loopback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, mongodb-atlas

Unable to connect to Mongo DB Atlas using mongodb+srv Protocol .
while trying to query some data - 
MongoError: cannot do raw queries on admin in atlas

Connection Properties i tried in datasource.json

```
mongoDb: {
connector: 'mongodb',
name: 'mongoDb',
url:"mongodb+srv://#username:#password@cluster0-kvw6a.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
}
```

while trying to query some data - getting this error

```
Unhandled error for request GET /api/Customers/getProfile?access_token=cMGG6C8fB8el0vbchpAzeOoTpH0N7Kf9va4b5k9Z6GrNAwgh4AtqQKlRYOyiWtsB: MongoError: cannot do
raw queries on admin in atlas
at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\maharah\customer_server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
at queryCallback (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\maharah\customer_server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:212:36)
at C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\maharah\customer_server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:469:18
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Connection Properties i tried in datasource.json

```
mongoDb: {
connector: 'mongodb',
name: 'mongoDb',
url:"mongodb+srv://#username:#password@cluster0-kvw6a.mongodb.net/test?
retryWrites=true&w=majority"
}
```

Comment: Please spend some time to properly format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have improved support for `mongodb+srv` protocol in April this year, see [PR #497](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/pull/497). You need to use `loopback-connector-mongodb` version `4.2.0` or newer.

Quoting from [README.md#using-the-mongodbsrv-protocol](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/blob/a6d0124c901dc727f8c47dfd532d9183f326de39/README.md#using-the-mongodbsrv-protocol):

MongoDB supports a protocol called `mongodb+srv` for connecting to replica sets without having to give the hostname of every server in the replica set.
To use `mongodb+srv` as the protocol set the `protocol` connection property in the datasource.json to `mongodb+srv`. For example:

```
"mydb": {
  "host": "myserver",
  "database": "test",
  "protocol": "mongodb+srv",
  "connector": "mongodb"
}
```

Note: the port is not specified when using the `mongodb+srv` protocol and will be ignored if given.